# Gitlab api to access private projects

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to retrieve the file and folders from a gitlab project. I used the following command:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${MY_TOKEN}" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}
```

The problem is, my project is private. Even though I am a member of the project, I cant use my access token to retrieve the project information. But if I take out the id from the command, and search for all the projects, I get a list of all the public projects. Is there something I have to do differently to access the private projects?

Thanks.

Comment: what response are you getting?

Comment: 404 Project not found

Comment: try this `curl --request GET 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234' --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxx'.`  Im guessing either there is space between `TOKEN` and `:` or `MY_TOKEN` doesn't have the correct value. Try hardcoding everything to check if it works, also dont put space between `PRIVATE-TOKEN` and `:`

Comment: Also, public projects dont need a token so it could be that your token is not being placed correctly or the request is incorrectly formatted

Comment: I tried the command: curl -k --request GET 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<Id>' --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN`:` <Token>' . Got the same error, 404 project not found

Comment: there should not be a space in between `PRIVATE-TOKEN:`

Comment: That is the most surprising part. PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN> gives me 401 unauthorized error. But if I wrap the : in backtics (`), it works. I am not sure why